# Find objects with unique parent relation object in CoreData Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I need help with 1 core data fetch request. I am having 2 entities

1. Department
2. Student (with scores property)
   So the Department can have multiple students.
   Now I want to fetch each student from different departments with the highest score.
   I have already made a query for sorting on scores. But want the only student from each (uniques) department

```
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Students")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "scores", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 50
fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
```

Please suggest, how we can find each student from each department with the highest score.

Now unfortunately I cannot use the result type as `NSDictionaryResultType`, as I am fetching data in NSFetchedResultsController. But want something like @distinctUnionOfObjects.
`[students valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.department"]`

Expected Output

1. Robin (Law) 74
2. Stephen (Mathematics) 98
3. John (Computer Science) 95
4. Tim (Electronics) 90
5. Johnson (Economics) 80

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: @zeytin question updated

Comment: @JoakimDanielson There was a performance issue with this one

Answer (score 0):

Guys I had followed the approach shared by @JoakimDanielson, but was facing a performance issue. So to improve the performance, I am also storing topStudent with score in department table. Now the performance hit is at insertion, whereas when rendering on UI thread is happening, the performance has improved drastically from `1.09 ms` to `450 usecs`. Note, I had also added indexing in department during fetching.